# Json - remove only key and assign value to parent key

Tags: javascript, json

```
{"empid":{"string":"31564604"},"joindate":{"date":2017-01-01}}
```

Convert the above json into below format using Java/Javascript. juzt need remove the datatype.

```
{"empid":"31564604","joindate":2017-01-01}
```

Comment: not a valid json , `2017-01-01`

Comment: Maybe choose what language you're working in, and show what you've tried already.

Comment: What library do you use for parsing creating jsons?

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript, convert it to an object then update by simply iterating over all properties and finally stringify the object.

```js
var json = '{"empid":{"string":"31564604"},"joindate":{"date":"2017-01-01"}}';

// parse the string
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
// get all keys and iterate over them
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
  // update the property with the nested object property value
  obj[k] = obj[k][Object.keys(obj[k])[0]];
})

// convert back to JSON
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

---

**UPDATE :** For nested object use the same with recursive approach.

```js
var json = '{"empid":{"string":"31564604"},"joindate":{"date":"2017-01-01"},"a":{"array":[{"number":1}]},"level1":{"object":{"level2":{"string":"abc"}}}}';

// parse the string
var object = JSON.parse(json);
updateObj(object);

function updateObj(obj) {
  // get all keys and iterate over them
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
    // update the property with the nested object property value
    obj[k] = obj[k][Object.keys(obj[k])[0]];
    // recursively call the faction if the element is object
    typeof obj[k] == 'object' && updateObj(obj[k]);
  })
}

// convert back to JSON
console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using `Array#reduce`.

```js
var obj = { empid: { string: 31564604 }, joindate: { date: '2017-01-01' }, nested: { nextLevel: { boolean: 1 } } },

    newObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(s, a) {
      s[a] = obj[a][Object.keys(obj[a])]
      return s;
    }, {});

    console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive approach with an object for getting the types right.

```js
function convert(object) {
    var dataTypes = { boolean: true, string: true, date: true };

    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        var key;
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
            key = Object.keys(object[k])[0];
            if (key in dataTypes) {
                object[k] = object[k][key];
            } else {
                convert(object[k]);
            }
        }
    });
}

var object = { empid: { string: '31564604' }, joindate: { date: '2017-01-01' }, nested: { nextLevel: { boolean: true } } };

convert(object);
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

If datatype is only specified for innermost element and not for the array or object then do it like.

```js
var json = '{"empid":{"string":"31564604"},"joindate":{"date":"2017-01-01"},"a":[{"number":1}],"level1":{"level2":{"string":"abc"}}}';

// parse the string
var object = JSON.parse(json);
updateObj(object);

function updateObj(obj) {
  // get all keys and iterate over them
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
    // get the nested object property
    var key = Object.keys(obj[k])[0];
    // update only if nested property is object
    typeof obj[k][key] != 'object' && (obj[k] = obj[k][key]);
    // recursively call the faction if the element is object
    typeof obj[k] == 'object' && updateObj(obj[k]);
  })
}

// convert back to JSON
console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
```

Comment: if it possible to remove the key "string" wherever in json and assign the value to previous key.

Comment: @karthickRangarajan : yes it's possible.. but in case it's a real property

Comment: @karthickRangarajan : can you give me an  example with nested structure ?

Answer (score 0):

Given the data:

```
const oldJson = {"empid":{"string":"31564604"},"joindate":{"date":"2017-01-01"}};
```

ES6:

```
let newJson = {};
Object.keys(oldJson).forEach(key => {
  newJson[key] = oldJson[key];
});
```

ES5:

```
var newJson = {};
Object.keys(oldJson).forEach(function(key) {
  newJson[key] = oldJson[key];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution : only with ES6 feature so you have to use `Babel`

```js
(function(){
  const oldJson = {"empid":{"string":"31564604"},"joindate":{"date":"2017-01-01"}};
  const newJson = Object.values( oldJson ).reduce( (acc, value) => Object.assign(acc, value), {})
  console.log(newJson);
})();
```

*Documentation :*

1. [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/values)
2. [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/assign)
3. [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce)